# Looping to set dropdown values - jquery object ref error

Tags: jquery

I am not really using the jQuery way of setting the value & text of this dropdown.  I'm not quite sure the jQuery way to set this, however the ref to the dropdown is definitely a jQuery object representing the dropdown.

So my variable holding the jQuery object that is referencing (represending) the dropdown is defined like this:

`ddlCar = $('#<%=ddlCar.ClientID %>');` // yes this is referencing an ASP.NET control id

ddlCar works fine in terms of referencing the dropdown...that's not the issue.

Now here's the code throwing an error and my initial problem:

```
for (key in carList) 
{
    ddlCar[0].options[i].text = carList[key].Name;
    ddlCar[0].options[i].value = carList[key].CarId;
    i++;
}
```

Error is: `ddlCar[0].options[i] is undefined`

Keep in mind this loop worked when I was referencing the dropdown using standard JS code with getElementByID but now I'm referencing the dropdown through a jQuery object ddlCar and so now the loop broke after changing my ddlCar to ref the dropdown through a jQuery object (using $('#<%=ddlCar.ClientID %>');`).

So for now, I kinda tried to hack this to work.  I know that adding [0] now will allow me to reference dropdown ref which is a jquery object as though it is a RAW DOM element so that I can use it like plain old JS syntax.  But for some reason, I still get undefined for ddlModel[0].options[i].  I know that ddlModel[0] is a valid object because I've used it like this in other parts of my code on the page:

```
ddlCar[0].options.length = ObjectCount(carList);
```

So I am curious why this loop is not working first and foremost.  I even tried this:

```
for (key in carList) 
{
    ddlCar[0].options[0][i].text = carList[key].Name;
    ddlCar[0].options[0][i].value = carList[key].CarId;
    i++;
}
```

And I guess last this is kinda a 2-part question.

What would be the jQuery way of setting the text and value of my dropdown?  I've already got a jQuery object ref to the dropodown so naturally I'm gonna refactor this later not to use JS for the rest of the syntax to set the values.

Answer (score 0):

```
for (key in carList) 
{
    $("<option/>",{text:carList[key].Name,value:carList[key].CarId}).appendTo(ddlCar[0])    
    i++;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot.  What's interesting also is I noticed that the same loop I've been using..if I ref the dropdown using a jQuery object and then do ddlCar[0], it's like my dropdown options array loses one in the total count so I end up with the last loop through trying to set the options array with an undefined for options[i_last] and I don't know why that is.

Comment: so I think your example is going the route of using the ddlCar as if I referenced it with getElementById right?  because it I ref via jQuery I wouldn't need the [0] after ddlCar right?

Comment: hmm tried your above but it did something weird...the dropdown had a bunch of blank entries after the list entries...

Comment: refereing to your second commentm yes you dont require `[0]` also when you put a `[0]` after the jquery object it returns a DOM element `ddlCar` is jquery object and `ddlCar[0]` is the DOM elem

Comment: cool right that makes sense.  Problem is with your code, I'm getting a bunch of blank list entries (same number as the length of the list) before I start to get the actual 17 entries in my select.  So I end up with 17 blanks and then 17 real values when I click on the dropdown menu for some reason.  I don't see how the hell it would be adding blank entries like that.  Weird...:)